# File Drag&Drop support for a RichTextBox (.Net)

Tags: drag-and-drop, outlook, richtextbox

What i try to do is:

- enable Drag&Drop of files for a TextBox (the dropped files should be shown as a small icon within the text).
- save the text and the dropped files to a DB.
- open the dropped file from the TextBox by doubleclick its icon.

The part of droping the file and show a icon within the text works fine but there are still some problems left:

- how can i save the path info of the dropped file to the icon representation within the TextBox. The automated Drag&Drop functions of the RichTextBox do it some how but i cant figure it out how. (As you can see (in listing 1) i try to paste a DataObject with two entries (the Image and the Path of the file) to the TextBox, but the path wont be saved).
- 2nd Problem is: how can i read the infos (filepath) of the doubleclicked file?
  (see listing 2 for one of may many fail attemts)
  How can i interpret the SeletedRTF to get my wanted Information?

Can anyone help me with this?

***Listing 1:***

```
Private Sub RTB_Kommentar_DragDrop(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles RTB_Kommentar.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent("FileDrop", True) = True Then
        Dim paths As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData("FileDrop"), Object)
        If (paths.Count > 0) Then
            Dim icon As Icon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(paths(0))
            Dim image = CreateTextBoxImage(paths(0), icon)

            Dim dObj As New DataObject()
            dObj.SetImage(image)
            dObj.SetText(paths(0))
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dObj)

            RTB_Kommentar.Paste()

            [...]

            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

***Listing 2:***

```
Private Sub RTB_Kommentar_DoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RTB_Kommentar.DoubleClick
    Dim dataObject As New DataObject()
    dataObject.SetDataObject(RTB_Kommentar.SelectedRtf)
    Dim img = dataObject.GetImage()
    Dim t = dataObject.GetText()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested i solved the problem.
With some Help of the following links:

[ExRichTextBox (on CodeProject) - Enhanced RichTextBox with insert functions for images or text](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4544/Insert-Plain-Text-and-Images-into-RichTextBox-at-R)
[OutlookDataObject (on CodeProject) - A object to get files that where dragged from Outlook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C)

After some heavy byte shoving iam now able to add files to the RichTextBox and reopen them on a duoble click.

You can find a sample project [here](http://uploaded.net/file/74svcf46)